# How can I train a naivebayes classifier incrementally?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, accord.net

Using Accord.NET I've created a NaiveBayes classifier. It will classify a pixel based on 6 or so sets of image processing results. My images are 5MP, so a training set of 50 images creates a very large set of training data.

6 int array per pixel * 5 million pixels * 50 images.

Instead of trying to store all that data in memory, is there a way to incrementally train the NaiveBayes classifier?  Calling Learn() multiple times overwrites the old data each time rather than adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now is not possible to train a Naive Bayes model incrementally using Accord.NET.

However, since all that Naive Bayes is going to do is to try to fit some distributions to your data, and since your data has very few dimensions, maybe you could try to learn your model on a subsample of your data rather than all of it at once.

When you go loading images to build your training set, you can try to randomly discard `x`% of the pixels in each image. You can also plot the classifier accuracy for different values of `x` to find the best balance between memory and accuracy for your model (hint: for such a small model and this large amount of training data, I expect that it wont make that much of a difference even if you dropped 50% of your data).